# How to insert a message at the first line if there is a failure in an AssertionScope in FluentAssertions?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, fluent-assertions

I'm looping through an array of results and comparing each object to the array of expected results `resultItem.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedResultItem)`. Each item have a unique identifier and want to display it above.

Here is an example result and the first two rows are from a single call of BeEquivalentTo while the 3rd entry is from a different one:

```
Expected property resultItem.PropertyA to be "85.01", but "85.00" differs near "0" (index 4).
Expected property resultItem.PropertyB to be 85.01M, but found 85.00M.
Expected step to be MyProject.Models.ResultItem
{
    IdA = "620",
    IdB = "Total", 
    PropertyA = "12156.00", 
    PropertyB = 12156.0M, 
    PropertyC = 33
}, but found <null>.
```

Is it possible to insert more details above each result as some form of header? Something like this:

```
Error found on entry (IdA:12, IdB: "ABC")
Expected property resultItem.PropertyA to be "85.01", but "85.00" differs near "0" (index 4).
Expected property resultItem.PropertyB to be 85.01M, but found 85.00M.
Error found on entry (IdA:620, IdB: "Total")
Expected step to be MyProject.Models.ResultItem
{
    IdA = "620",
    IdB = "Total", 
    PropertyA = "12156.00", 
    PropertyB = 12156.0M, 
    PropertyC = 33
}, but found <null>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't *ideal* readability, you can abuse FA's `because` argument to have it output some context:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void AssertionContext()
{
  using (new AssertionScope())
  {
    Foo resultItem = new Foo { PropA = "123.0", PropB = 123.0m, Id = 777 };
    resultItem.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new { PropA = "123.1", PropB = 123.1m }, "ID {0} should match", resultItem.Id);

    Foo step = null;
    step.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new Foo { PropA = "123.0", PropB = 123.0m }, "ID {0} should match", 987654);
  }
}
```

```
Expected property resultItem.PropA to be "123.1" because ID 777 should match, but "123.0" differs near "0" (index 4).
Expected property resultItem.PropB to be 123.1M because ID 777 should match, but found 123.0M.
Expected step to be Foo
{
    Id = 0, 
    PropA = "123.0", 
    PropB = 123.0M
} because ID 987654 should match, but found <null>.
```

Comment: Yeah, readability is quite awkward but a lot better than none. Anyway to make it a lot better? I can go as far as overriding or overloading as long as I don't have to re-implement a lot of classes and stuffs.

Comment: If it's a type you need more detailed failure messages for, you might consider writing assertion extensions specific to that type. In a previous project, I wrote a small extension for a `Result` type which allowed for assertions like `foo.Should().BeSuccessful()` and `foo.Should().HaveFailureCategory("EXPIRED").Which.Reason.Should().Contain($"valid until {date}")`. In your case, you could conceivably write one like `resultItem.Should().MatchItem(otherItem)` which upon failure constructs a specific message including the ID. https://fluentassertions.com/extensibility/